# MaxRetryError when scraping with selenium: happens when I quit and relaunch the browser

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

This is the snippet of the code. The error occurs in the last try-except block where I attempt to quit and relaunch the browser in case I encounter a TimeOut Exception.
Here is the error I get:

> MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=65067): 
>       Max retries exceeded with url: /session/819e6b641d55d1739500557218c88ce7/url 
>       (Caused by NewConnectionError(': 
>       Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] 
>       No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

Code:

```
def log_in(driver,uc_link,time_to_sleep):
            driver.get(uc_link)
            time.sleep(random.uniform(2,3))
            oldTab = driver.window_handles[0]
            driver.find_element_by_link_text("S&P Global NetAdvantage").click()
            time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
            """Change Focus to the new tab"""
            newTab = driver.window_handles[1]
            driver.switch_to_window(newTab)
            driver.switch_to_window(oldTab)
            driver.close()
            driver.switch_to_window(newTab)
            time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
```

#The loop

```
for num in range(start,end):
        print(num)
        b=len(name_found)
        try:
            if is_login(driver):
                log_in(driver,uc_link,5)
                try:
                    wait.until(driver.find_elements(By.ID, "ctl18_bottomBarLogo")) 
                except TimeoutException:
                    print("Log in taking too long")
                    driver.quit()
                    log_in(driver,uc_link,5)
            comp_name = fh['company1'][num]
            sp_comp = driver.find_element_by_id("SearchTopBar")
            sp_comp.clear()
            sp_comp.send_keys(comp_name)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ciqSearchSearchButton"]/input').click()
            try:
                wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements(By.ID, "CompanyHeaderInfo_CompanyHeaderInfo_BinderToolbar") or driver.find_elements(By.ID, "dropdownContainer"))
            except TimeoutException:
                print("Time Out")
                driver.quit() #Here is where the problem occurs
                #driver.refresh()
                time.sleep(10)
                log_in(driver,uc_link,5)
                continue
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the instantiate the driver again after quitting.

```
except TimeoutException:
                print("Time Out")
                driver.quit() #Here is where the problem occurs
                #driver.refresh()
                time.sleep(10)
                driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Path\To\Your\chromedriver.exe")
                log_in(driver,uc_link,5)
                continue
```

Stand alone example:

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

##############################
#### also inside the loop#####
############################## 
#log_in(driver, uc_link,5)
#actions = ActionChains(driver)
#wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
##############################
#### also inside the loop#####
##############################

for i in range(3):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Path\To\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.quit()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping out1 That worked for the iteration that was throwing TimeOut Exception. So, the code continues to run the loop for the next iteration but then returns the same error for the next iteration that doesn't return the same exception. I'll post the code down as a reply.

Comment: The function that first defines the driver, you did not post that function here.  Use your function that first defines the driver instead of my line.

Comment: That didn't work either. This is the function I had used: driver=webdriver.Chrome()

Comment: @Sanhitha Jugulum I guess I need to see more of your code to help troubleshoot. Does my standalone example work for you?

Comment: I just posted more code below! Thanks! And the stand-alone example worked.

Comment: @Sanhitha Jugulum everything that uses driver must go inside the loop. Right now everything you use `log_in, action, or wait` you will get an error. Initiate them again after the `driver.quit()`